# Stripe Checkout Session Django Subscription

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, stripe-payments

I'm not a developer or software engineer. We've put together almost the entirety of a web app with the help of chatgpt. It's worked great up to this point...

I would like to do the following:

```
Implement payments on my website through Stripe

Use the Stripe Checkout Session

Use the ui_mode = embedded option. I would like an embedded form not a redirect away from our website to Stripe's

Must use python django framework
```

The Stripe documentation has a guide that I'm sure is great for a flask app but I am really struggling to adapt it to django. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/embedded/quickstart?lang=python

Would any be able to help translate the flask documentation to a django framework?

Comment: The embedded form is not displaying on the page. There are no errors in terminal. The method that directs to Stripe's webpage can be made to work and I had it directing to Stripe's webpage. It's the embedded form that I am struggling with and have spent much time away from my family trying to get to work.

Please only comment if you intend to be helpful.